# ¿Que es fetch() en consulta preparada MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

En la página [oficial de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) existen varios ejemplos pero todos con nombres distintos.

Buscando en la web se habla pero en PDO, buscando en StackOverflow lo mismo se habla en PDO.

Pero qué significa en procedimientos de sentencias preparadas en orientado a objeto de MySQLi.

Yo tengo la siguiente línea de código.

```
$stmt->fetch();
```

¿Que significa?, Que hace esa línea de código.

Comment: @Shaz Por favor, algún comentario resumido es urgente gracias :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En mysqli, `fetch` es un método o función que se aplica al objeto [`mysqli_stmt`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-stmt.php) y que sirve para leer los resultados que devuelve dicho objeto. `fetch` podría traducirse en castellano como *ir a buscar*, o bien *traer*, *recuperar*. Esto es lo que hace `fetch` en esencia, traernos los resultados obtenidos.

Generalmente `fetch` se usa dentro de un bucle  (`while, foreach`), porque en cierto sentido este método lo que hace es colocar un puntero en los resultados obtenidos, empezando por el primer registro, para luego irlos recorriendo fila por fila.

Por eso casi siempre `fetch` se usa de este modo:

```
 /* obtener los valores */
    while ($sentencia->fetch()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $nombre, $código);
    }
```

---

### Los métodos derivados de `fetch`

El enlace que pones en tu pregunta (que apunta a las diferentes variantes de `fetch` en PDO), abre la puerta a que hablemos a otros métodos derivados de `fetch` que existen en `mysqli`.

Tanto como PDO (aunque ésta permite muchas más posibilidades y más interesantes), `mysqli` tienes varios métodos que podríamos llamar *variantes de `fetch`*, que nos permiten traer los resultados de una determinada manera según el uso posterior que querramos dar a dichos resultados.

Cabe decir que `fetch` sólo es aplicable al objeto `mysqli_stmt`, como dijimos más arriba. Mientras que estos otros métodos se pueden aplicar también al objeto [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php), para traer/leer los resultados que devuelven dichos objetos<sup>1</sup>.

Conviene enumerar estos métodos, los podemos encontrar en la [Sipnosis de la Clase `mysqli_result`, descrita en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php).

Son los siguientes:

- [**`fetch_all`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php): Obtiene todas las filas en un array asociativo, numérico, o en ambos.
- [**`fetch_array`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php): Obtiene una fila de resultados como un array asociativo, numérico, o ambos.
- [**`fetch_assoc`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php): Obtiene una fila de resultado como un array asociativo.
- [**`fetch_field_direct`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php): Obtiene los metadatos de un único campo.
- [**`fetch_field`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php): Obtiene el próximo campo del resultset.
- [**`fetch_fields`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php): Obtiene un array de objetos que representan los campos de un conjunto de resultados.
- [**`fetch_object`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php): Obtiene la fila actual de un conjunto de resultados como un objeto.
- [**`fetch_row`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php): Obtiene una fila de resultados como un array enumerado.

[No es tan rico como PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php), pero, *algo es algo* :). Además, cabe destacar que en `mysqli`, para que algunos de estos métodos funcionen, es necesario tener instalado el driver `mysqlnd`, lo cual es una dificultad añadida, que hace a `mysqli` menos atractivo (al menos para mi), ya que estarás programando código que en parte quizá no funcione, al depender de un driver externo. Para mí es un grave error de los diseñadores de mysqli.

Espero te sirva.

---

#### Notas:

<sup>1</sup>`fetch` por el contario, no es aplicable al objeto `mysqli_result`. Cuando intentamos leer los resultados devueltos por este objeto usando `fetch`, tenemos la siguiente excepción: `Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch()`. Nótese que esto es aplicable para el método [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php), el cual suele usarse cuando no hay necesidad de consultas preparadas y cuyo resultado es también un objeto `mysqli_result`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hace es rellenar las variables vinculadas al statement mediante la función `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()`, dicha función devuelte 2 valores

1. TRUE    Éxito.
2. FALSE   Ocurrió un error

   ```
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "world");

   /* comprobar la conexión */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
       exit();
   }

   $consulta = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 150,5";

   if ($sentencia = $mysqli->prepare($consulta)) {

   /* ejecutar la sentencia */
   $sentencia->execute();

   /* vincular las variables de resultados */
   $sentencia->bind_result($nombre, $código);

   /* obtener los valores */
   while ($sentencia->fetch()) {
       printf ("%s (%s)\n", $nombre, $código);
   }

   /* cerrar la sentencia */
   $sentencia->close();
   }

   /* cerrar la conexión */
   $mysqli->close();
   ```

Tomado de la documentación de php http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php